# Multiply columns with both integers and strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, multiplication

I have a large DataFrame with 50+ columns. I want to multiply every column by another column, however some strings exist within the data.

```
df[df.loc[:, df.columns != "Total Balance"].columns].multiply(df["Total Balance"], axis="index")
```

The `df.loc[:, df.columns != "Total Balance"` operation is so that I dont multiply the Total Balance by itself.

My issue is that some of the elements in the DataFrame are strings, thuus I get the error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

When an integer is multiplied by a string, I want the Dataframe to fill that spot with NaN. I have checked the docs and there is no built in default argument. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to coerce your dataframe into a numeric table with strings replaced by NaN (unless they're strings that can be converted to a numeric like `"5.0"`)

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Then do whatever you need.

Comment: TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: Ahh yea sorry - forgot that this wasn't something that took a dataframe. Fixed it.